# Read a line from the screen with ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

How do I read a line of text printed on a pad in ncurses? I am trying to use the `ncurses` function `winchnstr`. I am confused about how to use `chtype*` in the function. I understand that `chtype` is a `long int`, but when I use `chtype` in my code I get a segment fault. In the below example the `long int y` prints 20. I need to be able to read a line of text on the pad. Can someone show me how to do it?

```
long int p[20];
wmove(pad,prow,ccol);
long int y = winchnstr(pad, p,20)&A_CHARTEXT;
```

> Edit:

Whenever I print the return from the function, I get the number of characters returned. I am confused. How can I turn this into a printable string?

```
fprintf(file,"%d",y);
```

Answer (score 0):

**`winchnstr`** adds a trailing null, and you already asked for it to return as many characters as would fit in the array.  So that's addressing past the end of the array.

The [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inchstr.3x.html) says

> The four functions with *n* as the last argument, return a leading substring at  most  *n*  characters  long
>   (***exclusive*** of the trailing **`(chtype)0`**).

**`winchnstr`** returns **`chtype`** values, which have a character combined with video attributes.  You cannot directly convert an array of **`chtype`** data to a string.  But curses has a function [**`winnstr`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_instr.3x.html) which returns only a character string (no video attributes).  Again, keep in mind that the trailing null is not included in the length which you specify for the function.

Comment: That makes sense, I am still having trouble understanding how to get the string from the function. Can you check my edits and hopefully tell me the proper way to turn the output of winchstr into a string?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that works to extract a character for peoples use.

```
chtype p[150];
winchstr(pad, p);
char y = p[0] & A_CHARTEXT;
```

y will then hold the character under the cursor.

Comment: The screenshots [here](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-slang.html#compare_picsmap) were wider than 150 characters, so your suggested solution would not work.